# Rellenar array con números aleatorios sin repetirse

Tags: java, while

Tengo este código que genera números aleatorios y los rellena en un array solo si no se repiten.
'''

```
static void rellenaArray(int[] array) {
    Random r = new Random();
    boolean repetido = true;
    int numeroAIntroducir = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        while (repetido) {
            numeroAIntroducir = r.nextInt(15);
            repetido = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[j] == numeroAIntroducir) {
                    repetido = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        array[i] = numeroAIntroducir;
        repetido = true;
    }
}
```

El problema es que no logro ver por qué no sale del bucle while al establecer que repetido = false después de generar un número aleatorio.

Muchas gracias

Comment: No veo la longitud del array pero... si la longitud del array es 15 justa esto puede llevarle un buen rato (hay veces que algunos números se resisten a salir al "azar"). Y si la longitud es > 15, esto que tienes es un bucle infinito puesto que nunca jamás vas a poder rellenar una lista de 16 números con solo 15 sin repetir uno.

Comment: Gracias por responder y perdona por no formular correctamente la pregunta. El array es de longitud 12, pero no es dónde me he quedado atascado. El tema es que al generar un número aleatorio evaluará si está repetido buscando en los elementos anteriores del array siempre y cuando repetido = true. Lo que no veo es por qué no sale automaticamente del while si después de generar un aleatorio se pone la condición repetido a false.

Comment: El truco para generar número aleatorios sin repetirlos, es crear un array con los números y luego desordenarlos. Es decir la aleatoriedad la aplicas en el orden no en la generación

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo https://www.online-java.com/OhgFiDxnPR

Comment: Gracias, pero mi duda no es la generación de números aleatorios. Es algo mucho más de base y que yo creía tener controlado. El problema es que no veo por qué no sale del bucle while al negar la condición.

Comment: Por eso es importante no sobre anidar, porque es difícil ver lo que pasa. En cualquier caso el código que has publicado SI sale del while y no tiene problema alguno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te dice @Yussef, tu código funciona "bien", pongo bien entre comillas, porque como te indica @Benito-B, no es la forma correcta de hacerlo, en teoría, no hay nada que impida que el método tarde... digamos dos horas en ejecutarse, si, en la práctica es casi imposible, pero la probabilidad está ahí, entonces te propongo este camino:

Creamos una lista con los números deseados, la recorremos, y aleatoriamente le quitamos uno, que agregamos al array de salida.

```
int[] generaArrayDesordenado( int numeroMayor, int largoArray ) {

      // creamos una lista y la llenamos en orden
   List<Integer> listaNumeros = new ArrayList<>();
   for( int i = 0; i < numeroMayor; i++ ) {
      listaNumeros.add( i );         
   }

      // creamos el array de salida y lo recorremos
   int salida[] = new int[ largoArray ];
   for( int i = 0; i < salida.length; i++ ) {
      Random r = new Random();

         // generamos el aleatorio en base al largo de la lista
      int indice = r.nextInt( listaNumeros.size() );

         // inicializamos el array con el valor que quitamos (con remove) de la lista
      salida[ i ] = listaNumeros.remove( indice );         
   }
   return salida;
}
```